# Передать значение переменной JS в стиль CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Нужно передать диву ширину, значение которой вычисляется в JS.

```
<div id="score"></div>
```

Нужно для `#score` присвоить ширину из переменной `score`, которая равна `20*2.5`, в процентах

Answer (score 4):

Что бы передать значение стиля элементу, нужно обратиться к элементу, использовать функцию `style` и там прописывать, что именно вы хотите менять

**Вариант 1**:

Стиль применяется напрямую через названия переменных.

Пример:
Что бы установить `background-color`, я буду писать `obj.style.backgroundColor`

```js
var score = 20 * 2.5;

document.querySelector('#score').style.width = score + '%';
```

```css
#score {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="score"></div>
```

**Вариант 2**:

Стили применяются через переменные из CSS

Пример:
Что бы установить `background-color`, я буду прямо писать `obj.style['background-color']`

```js
var score = 20 * 2.5;

document.querySelector('#score').style['width'] = score + '%';
```

```css
#score {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="score"></div>
```

Comment: Вы отклонили мою правку - чем конкретно отличаются варианты 1 и 2?

Comment: @br3t, 1) Вы не правильно написали, это для стилей с дефис, я могу и тут написать `style.backgroundColor`. 2) Мне кажется, что разница очевидна

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, информацию об отличиях этих вариантов в ответ.

Comment: @br3t, не вижу потребности. Ответ даже не приняли. Ну разве что для будущих пользователей

Comment: `style['background-color']` - почему-то мне кажется, что это не по стандарту...

Comment: @Qwertiy, я про стандарт написал что-то?